# How to handle passwords prompts in expectj

Tags: jsch, expectj

I would like to send "su root" command via expectj (in fact it is jsch).It requests password. Is there a way to handle it in expectj ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ExpectJ ex = new ExpectJ(30);
    Spawn spawn = ex.spawn(new SshSpawn("192.168.56.101", 22, "alice", "alicepassword"));
    spawn.send("su root\n");
    spawn.expect("assword");
    spawn.send("yourpassword\n");
    try{
        spawn.interact();   
    }catch(NullPointerException npe){   
        //ignore, seems like some strange expectj bug
    }
```